# how to configure a shiro Realm to connect to an oracle database within a struts2 application

Tags: java, oracle, struts2, jboss, shiro

I have been working with shiro (ki, jsecurity) now for a few days and have been able to create a test application.  I am working with struts2, off JBoss.  I have been able create a shiro.ini file with a few hard-coded users, and i have gotten that to work. It seems like the API within JAVA is extremely easy to get a grasp of, so integrating shiro to my application and making it functional hasnt been the real problem.  My real issue is that i have not been able to find any form of documentation on how to create/tie a REALM to an oracle database using this set up.  I have found several examples and tried aimlessly to adapt it to my situation.  but i have been unable.

I have an oracle database with a USERS table, it simply holds a username, password, and role.  If i am able to make the connection, it seems as though it should simply fit right into my current login/logoff app.

I added the following lines to my web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
        <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher> 
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher> 
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher> 
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

I then added shiro.ini to my WEB-INF:

```
[main]

[users]
bruins = boston, admin, super, worker
rangers = newyork, super, worker
leafs = toronto, worker

[urls]
/authoring/logout = logout
/authoring/** = authc
```

after that it was simply calling the java code from within my loginAction.java:

```
Factory<SecurityManager> factory = new IniSecurityManagerFactory("classpath:shiro.ini");
SecurityManager securityManager = factory.getInstance();   
SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager(securityManager);   
Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();   
UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(this.username, this.password);
try {   
    currentUser.login(token);   
    Session session = currentUser.getSession();   
    session.setAttribute("user", this.username);   
} catch (UnknownAccountException uae) {   
  ... 
} catch (IncorrectCredentialsException iae) {   
 ...
} catch (LockedAccountException lae) {   
 ... 
} catch (AuthenticationException ae) {   
  ...         
} catch (Exception e) {   
 ...
}   
ActionMessages messages = new ActionMessages();
if (currentUser.isAuthenticated()) {   
    System.out.println("user is authenticated!!!!!");

    if (currentUser.hasRole("admin")){
        System.out.println(this.username + " can access admin functions");
    }
    if(currentUser.hasRole("super")){
        System.out.println(this.username + " can access supervisor functions");
    }
    if(currentUser.hasRole("worker")){
        System.out.println(this.username + " can only perform worker functions");
    }
    addActionMessage(getText("success.valid.user", this.username));
    return SUCCESS;
} else {   
    System.out.println("user was not authenticated!!!!!!");
    addActionError(getText("error.login"));
    return ERROR;
}
```

so all in all, i have the application working with hard-coded users:  my question is what is the best way for me to set up the REALM to connect to my oracle database?  I have seen it online done in several different ways, and i have been unable to adapt any of them to my set up, and i would love to get this going to that i can continue to familiarize myself with the API.

thanks - John

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Shiro's JdbcRealm using a connection-pooling DataSource configured in shiro.ini, e.g. with [BoneCP](http://jolbox.com/):

```
[main]
ds = com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource
ds.driverClass = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
ds.jdbcUrl = dbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:myschema
ds.username = scott
ds.password = tiger
# other BoneCP connection pool settings as desired

jdbcRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
jdbcRealm.dataSource = $ds
# you can customize the authenticationQuery, userRolesQuery and permissionsQuery
# if needed.

securityManager.realms = $jdbcRealm
```

We use BoneCP in production and are quite happy with it.

You can look at the [JdbcRealm's source code](https://github.com/apache/shiro/blob/1.2.x/core/src/main/java/org/apache/shiro/realm/jdbc/JdbcRealm.java) to see how it works.  You can customize the queries to match your database schema.

Also, you could of course subclass JdbcRealm to customize to your needs if the default settings/queries won't work. [Here's an example](http://blog.pinateknoloji.com/shiro-jdbc-realm) of a custom JdbcRealm (it also uses JNDI to look up the datasource if you want to do that instead of configure the datasource in shiro.ini).

Comment: Les, that helps a ton thank you very much. However, I still have a question in regards to the datasource. As of now, I already have a datasource within my application.. So from my point of view i have 2 options (please correct me if im wrong, there may be more, or one of these may not work...) A - to define my DS in the .ini file. OR B - to define my Realm file in the .ini file, then call my current DS using java from my Realm file. I have no opposition to either, im actually just curious if one method may be safer/more effective.   -thanks, John

Comment: Approach B is probably better than A since the rest of your App won't be dependent upon Shiro config.  However, there is an even cleaner approach: implement the [Factory](http://shiro.apache.org/static/1.2.2/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/util/Factory.html) interface to acquire your app DS and return it from the getInstance() method.  Then you can configure this:

    ds = com.my.DatasourceFactory
    jdbcRealm.dataSource = $ds

Comment: @LesHazlewood would the factory be returning the BoneCP connection pool or the  actual connection? Thanks for the great answer so far btw.

Comment: @frostymarvelous the connection pooling data source.